# Find multiple files in the same directory

Tags: c#, .net, linq, visual-studio

I'm trying to find, giving a path, a list of files that have same filename but different extensions (`.bak` and `.dwg`) in the same directory.

I have this code:

```
String[] FileNames = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Where(s => s.EndsWith(".bak") || s.EndsWith(".dwg")).ToArray();
var queryDupNames = from f in FileNames
                    group f by Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(f) into g
                    where g.Count() > 1                                            
                    select new { Name = g.Key, FileNames = g };
```

This works great to locate files with the same filename but in the whole system. I need only to obtain those that are in the same directory.

For example:

```
- Dir1\filename1.bak
- Dir1\filename1.dwg
- Dir1\filename2.bak
- Dir1\filename2.dwg
- Dir1\filename3.dwg
- DiferentDir\filename1.bak
- DiferentDir\filename1.dwg
- DiferentDir\filename3.dwg
```

The result should be:

```
- Dir1\filename1.bak
- Dir1\filename1.dwg
- Dir1\filename2.bak
- Dir1\filename2.dwg
- DiferentDir\filename1.bak
- DiferentDir\filename1.dwg
```

But with my code, filename3 is also included due to

```
g.count() > 1
```

it's true. It's grouping by only filename... I tried to fix with this code but I got 0 results:

```
String[] FileNames = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Where(s => s.EndsWith(".bak") || s.EndsWith(".dwg")).ToArray();
var queryDupNames = from f in FileNames
                    group f by new { path = Path.GetLongPath(f), filen = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(f) } into g
                    where g.Count() > 1                                            
                    select new { Name = g.Key, FileNames = g };
```

Any help or clue?

Thanks

Comment: `Path` doesn't have a method `GetLongPath`. Are you using AlphaFS? Did you try with `GetDirectoryName` ?

Comment: I´m using Delimon dll due to long path string problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31919748/directory-getfiles-stops-searching-when-error

Comment: In which case the problem is the library, not the LINQ code. Are your paths really relative? Does the library support relative paths?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[System.IO.Path](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.IO.Path_methods(v=vs.110).aspx) doesn't have a GetLongPath method. I suspect you are using an external library like AlphaFS. In any case, `GetLongPath` returns the full *file* path, not the path of the file's folder.

The file's folder path is returned by `GetDirectoryName` both in System.IO and other libraries like AlphaFS. The following snippet will return only `Dir1\filename1`, `Dir1\filename2` and `DifferentDir\filename1`

```
var files = new[]
{
    @"c:\Dir1\filename1.bak",
    @"c:\Dir1\filename1.dwg",
    @"c:\Dir1\filename2.bak",
    @"c:\Dir1\filename2.dwg",
    @"c:\Dir1\filename3.dwg",
    @"c:\DiferentDir\filename1.bak",
    @"c:\DiferentDir\filename1.dwg",
    @"c:\DiferentDir\filename3.dwg",
};

var duplicates =   from file in files
                    group file by new
                    {
                        Folder = Path.GetDirectoryName(file),
                        Name = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file)
                    } into g
                    where g.Count()>1
                    select new
                    {
                        Name = g.Key,
                        Files = g.ToArray()
                    };
```

Comment: Seems to be working!! I´ll try with a large mapped drive and I tell you... thanks anyway!

Comment: BTW GetLongPath returns the file's full path name, not the folder's. It's like trying to group by the full file's path

Answer (score 0):

first find all folders.

then for each folder find all the files with same name but different extension.
something like this:

```
        var list = new List<string>();
        foreach (var subDirectory in Directory.EnumerateDirectories(@"C:\Temp"))
        {
            var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(subDirectory);
            var repeated = files.Select(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension)
                .GroupBy(x => x)
                .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
                .Select(y => y.Key);
            list.AddRange(repeated);
        }
```

tested on .net 4.6

Comment: The OP already has all files from all folders, that's not the problem. The question asks how to group by folder and extension, and why the current approach fails

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos it´s right. Your code is interesting but I can´t use it because I need to support long path names and multiple subfolders with Delimon dll http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31919748/directory-getfiles-stops-searching-when-error/31920319#31920319